# Sort Combobox items binded with ObservableCollection of enum

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, combobox, observablecollection

I have simple combobox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="elementTypesComboBox" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=NVP.ElementType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=NVP.CEB, Converter={StaticResource CanAddNewElementConverter}, FallbackValue=false}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ElementTypeToStringConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

binded with:

```
     ObservableCollection<ElementTypes> elementTypes = new ObservableCollection<ElementTypes>();
```

where 'ElementTypes' is enum and collection is filled with all enum values. Example:

```
public enum ElementTypes
{
    E2, 
    E5,
    E6,
    E1
}
```

I just wanna sort my combobox items.

I tried:

1) First sollution:

```
 elementTypesComboBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending)); 

 elementTypesComboBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Content", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

2) Secund sollution

```
elementTypes = new ObservableCollection<UndrawnElementTypes>(elementTypes.OrderBy(i => i));
elementTypesComboBox.ItemsSource = elementTypes;
```

None of this does not work. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you want order to be like "E1, E2, E5, E6" ? If so, define enum members in `ElementTypes` in this order. So you should have `public enum ElementTypes {E1, E2, E5, E6}`.

Comment: I can do It, but for another language it will not be the same order. I need generic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ToString()` in `OrderBy()` to sort the ComboBox items alphabetically:

```
elementTypesComboBox.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ElementTypes))
    .Cast<ElementTypes>()
    .OrderBy(e => e.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

You may sort any predefined subset of `ElementTypes` the same way:

```
IEnumerable<ElementTypes> elements = ...

elementTypesComboBox.ItemsSource = elements
    .OrderBy(e => e.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This answer showed me my mistake. Instead (i => i) I should have used (i => i.ToString()). It works, but it leave "empty space" which supposed to be first item in combobox in the middle of combobox list. It item does not exist in my enum. I do not know why it put that item in the middle of combobox. I cannot use this unswer because it take all enum elements, I have some conditions and cannot change element in collection or combobox, just need to sort them.

Comment: You can sort any collection of ElementTypes the same way. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, problem is solved. Empty space in combo box is  the result of some convert method which translates some string in empty space.